# Сравнение числа с элементами массива.

Tags: массивы, java

Здравствуйте! У меня есть цифровой массив, и есть число, получаемое в результате арифметических действий.
Задача - сравнить число с ячейками массива и вывести на экран все показатели массива, которые больше или равны числу. Спасибо.

Comment: может андроид тут не причём?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно решение на основе готового кода то могу предложить интерфейс NavigableSet и класс-реализатор TreeSet. и метод tailSet. вам нужно предварительно сделать так чтобы массив был в непримитивном типе:

```
    Integer[] numbers={1,2,3,4,5}; //
    Collection<Integer> coll=Arrays.asList(numbers);
    NavigableSet<Integer> set=new TreeSet<>(coll);
    Set<Integer> result=set.tailSet(3,true); //число результат. метод вернет коллекцию со значениями больше или равно тройки.
```